# Java SHA1 hash to base64 : unsigned bytes?

Tags: c#, java, base64, sha1, unsigned

I am trying to **hash** a value (**SHA1**) in both **C#** and **Java**, and then return a **base64** representation. I get 2 different results.

I know this is because Java uses **signed bytes** while C# **doesn't**.

**C# version** :

```
static public string toSHA1(string toEncrypt)
{
    return toSHA1(toEncrypt, new UTF8Encoding());
}

static public string toSHA1(string toEncrypt, Encoding encoding)
{
    String salt = "fE4wd#u*d9b9kdKszgè02ep5à4qZa!éi6";
    SHA256Managed sha256hasher = new SHA256Managed();
    byte[] hashedDataBytes = sha256hasher.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(toEncrypt + salt));
    return Convert.ToBase64String(hashedDataBytes);
}
```

**Java version** :

```
public static String toSHA1(String toEncrypt) {
    return toSHA1(toEncrypt, "UTF-8");
}

public static String toSHA1(String toEncrypt, String encoding) {
    String salt = "fE4wd#u*d9b9kdKszgè02ep5à4qZa!éi6";
    String res = null;
    toEncrypt = toEncrypt + salt;
    try {
        byte[] dataBytes = toEncrypt.getBytes(encoding);
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        res = Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest(dataBytes));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return res;
}
```

I can't manage to find a solution to get the correct **base64** result using **Java**.

Converting **signed** values to **unsigned** ones forces the use of `int` data type, but as soon as I put it in a `byte` data type, I get my **signed** bytes back...

`Base64.encodeBytes` is waiting for a `byte` array, so is there any way I can pass an **unsigned** `byte` array to this method ? What can I do with that `int` array ? :

```
int[] dataInt = new int[dataBytes.length];
// signed to unsigned
for (int i=0; i<dataBytes.length; i++)
{
    dataInt[i] = (dataBytes[i] & 0xFF);
}
```

I **can't** modify the **C#** version, I have to adapt the **Java** version to give the same results.

Comment: "I know this is because Java uses signed bytes while C# doesn't." No, that's almost certainly *not* the reason.

Comment: When comparing my 2 byte arrays, I can see negative values in the java version. The difference is exactly 256 with the C# version.

Comment: That surprises me greatly, given that in C# you're using SHA-256 and in the Java code you're using SHA-1. The byte arrays shouldn't even be the same size, as the result of SHA-1 is 160 bits, and the result of SHA-256 is 256 bits.

Comment: Sorry indeed I was comparing `encoding.GetBytes(toEncrypt + salt)` and `toEncrypt.getBytes(encoding)` just to see the signed/unsigned differences, and thought it was the source of the problem...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is very simple... From your C# code:

```
SHA256Managed sha256hasher = new SHA256Managed()
```

SHA-256 != SHA-1. Use the [`SHA1`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1.aspx) class instead in C#, or use SHA-256 in Java as well. As you apparently can't change the C# code, you should change the Java instead:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
```

Once you've done that, the base64-encoded data should be the same in both platforms. Even though bytes are signed in Java, base64 encoders *treat* them as unsigned... they're only interested in the bits, basically.

I'd also strongly suggest that you represent your salt in ASCII in the source code, using `\uxxxx` escaping for any non-ASCII characters. This will prevent problems due to compiling using the wrong encoding.

Comment: What strikes me as odd is that this answer should be very clear. A Base64-encoded SHA256 hash is a full 32 bytes longer than the Base64 encoded SHA1.

Comment: @Phylogenesis: Surely it's 16 characters... Base64-encoded SHA-1 is 28 characters; base-64 encoded SHA-256 is 44 characters.

Comment: You're right, I was mentally calculating the Base64 expansion of the hex string.

Comment: OMG I spent one hour on this, convinced it was a signed/unsigned issue... Thank you for the tips.